# How can I convert the blue color of water into another even if there are different shades of blue present?

Tags: python, image

[image]

How can I convert the blue color of of the water in an image into white, especially if there are different shades of blue. And then separate any other color and give it for instance black. An example would be this pollution in the sea and you want to detect the contaminated area and give it a color clearly distinguishable from the water:

[image]

Comment: I tried with a code writing but the result was vary from one image to other. Especially it is my first time in programming language

Comment: No worries, if it is a wrong approach. Please edit your question and post your attempts, so people  see, which libraries you have used. The more specific your question is the higher the chances that you get a response. This is the reason, the help section asks for [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes you are right , these were my codes .

Comment: I posted two of my answers which they are not detecting the blue color efficiently ...

Comment: And you know I am trying to separate any color from the blue . As you can see there is a oil spill in the water and I am trying to give the spill clear, obvious color (green, red, black, etc ) which will be easy to calculate the total area of the pollution

Comment: I am afraid, I was not clear enough. [Please don't post your code attempts in the answer section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), if they don't work as intended. [Edit your question instead](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50186537/edit). And when you post your code on SO, please try to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
BLUE = [255,0,0]
img1 = cv2.imread('11.jpg')
replicate = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)     
reflect = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)
reflect101 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101)
wrap = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_WRAP)
constant= 
cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=BLUE)
plt.subplot(231),plt.imshow(img1,'gray'),plt.title('ORIGINAL')
plt.subplot(232),plt.imshow(replicate,'gray'),plt.title('REPLICATE')
plt.subplot(233),plt.imshow(reflect,'gray'),plt.title('REFLECT')
plt.subplot(234),plt.imshow(reflect101,'gray'),plt.title('REFLECT_101')
plt.subplot(235),plt.imshow(wrap,'gray'),plt.title('WRAP')
plt.subplot(236),plt.imshow(constant,'gray'),plt.title('CONSTANT')
plt.show()
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: An uncommented, unexplained lump of code is not much use to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image

import colorsys

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def rgb2gray(rgb):
return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

img = mpimg.imread('0.jpg')     
gray = rgb2gray(img)    
plt.imshow(gray, cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.show()

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: So, do you propose something else or better idea !